# Conditional statement checking two conditions for CPT and Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I am trying to write a conditional statement which checks if the single custom post type also has a custom taxonomy term associated with it. 
My code is:

```
if (is_singular('my_cpt')) && (has_term('myterm', 'mytaxonomy', $post->ID )) {
```

But somehow, I am getting unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because your code has syntax error. It should be this.

```
if ( is_singular('my_cpt') && ( has_term( 'myterm', 'mytaxonomy', $post->ID ) ) ) {

}
```

Did you notice `if` condition should close just after `is_singular('my_cpt')`.